# Copying files using Copy in batch script copies only the first file to the destination folder

Tags: windows, windows-scripting

This is my copy command :

```
set POLL="C:\Documents and Settings\"
copy Register.class+Ca.class+pack %POLL% /-Y
```

**pack** is a folder here. 
The result of the above copy coman is that only Register.class gets copied to the destination folder. What's my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naming multiple source files for a copy command copies the files into one single file.

```
copy fileone + filetwo filethree
```

would result in filethree containing the content of fileone AND filetwo. You cannot copy multiple files to a different location with copy.

However it is fairly easy to do so using either a loop or xcopy-command:

```
set POLL="C:\Documents and Settings\"
FOR %%F IN (Register.class Ca.class) DO copy %%F %POLL% /-Y
xcopy pack %POLL% /-Y
```

Comment: i guess i missunderstood the syntax of copy the same way you did. I have changed the answer to something useful.

Comment: I think using xcopy should work. There are also other copy tools like robocopy which could help, but those are not included with windows by default

Comment: hmmm you could xcopy source destination /EXCLUDE:fileidontwant. Note that the for loop in my answer is not in the loop. The Loop is on the first line using only the copy command. xcopy is used to copy the pack-folder. Have you looked at robocopy? (http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc733145(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Ashwin: did you define POLL as variable? Also: Are you running the script from the same folder where the .class files are in?

Comment: It worked when I changed the %F to %%F. I don't know why but it works. Please edit your answer and I will accept your question

Comment: Ah sorry. You are right %%F should be used in Batch-files. I tested it on command line where %F works...